# Steep "compatibility" warning

Tags: ruby, rbs, steep

I'd like to have a Ruby class method return an instance on reading from a file.  And I'd like that method to either take a string which is the path to the file, or an IO where the caller has opened the file themselves.  And I'd like to do this for a few methods in a few classes, so I define a helper module:

```rb
module IOUtil
  extend self

  def io_with_mode(arg, mode)
    case arg
    when String
      File.open(arg, mode) do |io|
        yield io
      end
    when File
      yield arg
    else
      raise TypeError, arg
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_reader :str

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def self.from_bar(arg)
    IOUtil.io_with_mode(arg, 'r') do |io|
      new(io.read)
    end
  end
end
```

That all works nicely, if I have a file `bar.dat` with some text in it then

```rb
bar1 = Foo.from_bar('bar.dat')
puts bar1
puts bar1.str

bar2 = File.open('bar.dat') { |io| Foo.from_bar(io) }
puts bar2
puts bar2.str
```

then I get

```
#<Foo:0x00007f853ae1d1d0>
Hello
#<Foo:0x00007f853ae1c500>
Hello
```

I want to type-check this so create the signature file which I *think* is right:

```rb
module IOUtil
  extend IOUtil
  def io_with_mode: [T] (String | IO, String) { (IO) -> T } -> T
end

class Foo
  def initialize: (String) -> void
  def str: () -> String
  def self.from_bar: (String | IO) -> instance
end
```

and `steep check` gives me a pass, but the warning

```
[Steep 1.6.0] 
[typecheck:typecheck@2] [background] 
[#typecheck_source(path=lib/minimal.rb)] 
[#type_check_file(lib/minimal.rb@lib)] 
[synthesize:(1:1)] 
[synthesize:(18:1)] 
[synthesize:(19:3)] 
[synthesize:(25:3)] 
[::Foo <: instance] 
`T <: instance` doesn't hold generally, but testing it with 
`::Foo <: instance && instance <: ::Foo` for compatibility
```

Is there anything to worry about here? I don't really understand why the warning.

If not, is there a way to quieten the warning?